# How to generate valid certificates for instances created from GCE instance templates?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I am generating Google Compute Engine instances from [instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates). The problem is I need to create certificates for each instance, and certificates need to be for each instance's hostname. Now, instance hostnames contain a random part, f.ex. *staging-node-ntsr.c.example.internal*. How can I generate certificates that correspond to these dynamically generated hostnames?

I use [cfssl](https://cfssl.org/) to generate certificates, my command line looks like this:

```
cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem -config=ca-config.json -profile=client-server worker.json | cfssljson -bare worker-client
```

The context is that I need to TLS secure my Kubernetes nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by generating certificates on each instance as part of bootstrapping, because then I know each instance's various addresses.